# Facebook gives 403 error for my website - Updated Information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, web-hosting

I have a website where i added facebook og tags. http://bowarrow.de No matter what i try and what i change i always get a 403 Error in the debugger.

Though it can access my site somehow. I read every question about this and in the last question i asked about it, no one could really help me. So i decided i ask on facebook and could find the following:

> In this case, your site is definitely returning a 403 error to at
>   least some of the requests from the debugger. This is something
>   happening in your code or hosting infrastructure
>
> $curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i 'http://bowarror.de/' HTTP/1.1
>   403 Forbidden Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 16:03:55 GMT Server: Apache
>   Content-Length: 2940 Content-Type: text/html
>
> Host Europe GmbH – bowarrow.de   [...]

I tried it myself and can confirm that i can't get any access with that facebook header. I asked hostgator several times if there is a server problem on their site and they denied. So maybe i think it might have something to do with host europe, where my domain is registered?

I linked the domain to my hosting through a-records because host europe doesn't support nameserver changes.

Any ideas, help?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your own software doing this? the error message in the body of the response is `<h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;">This site is currently under construction.</h2>` in English, `<h2 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;">Diese Webpr&auml;senz befindet sich noch im Aufbau.</h2>` in German

Either your code, or that of your hosting company, is causing the response to Facebook to be a 403 error, it's nothing to do with where the domain name is registered

Comment: Not so sure about that but the hoster is hostgator and i just installed wordpress on it. I also tested a simple html index file without wordpress and there was the same.

This is getting annoying because i can't find anything like that in my code. Does it tell you where this error page is coming from somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Okay i've found probably what caused it. The reason for this was that i use my domain from hosteurope with hostgator. Because hosteurope doesn't allow nameserver changes i had to change the a-records.

Unfortunally there were some AAAA records IPv6 that i didn't change, because hostgator doesn't support ipv6 in my hosting.

Facebook was crawling these ipv6 and sent a 403 to the debugger. (Because there was no ipv6 server that it could have access to)

Yesterday i deleted them and it nearly immediately startet working. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bowarrow.de%2F

Unfortunally it only works for the URL with www. without it i still get a 403.

see here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbowarrow.de%2F

Comment: Thanks so much! I was tearing my hair out with this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using the 10Web Social Post Feed WordPress plugin, follow these steps:

1. Go to Facebook Feed WD > Options page and press Uninstall.
2. Uninstall the plugin by following the steps in this video.
3. Navigate to Plugins page and delete Facebook Feed WD
4. Reinstall and activate it.
5. Re-Authenticate your facebook account and recreate your feeds.